# How do I count the number of words in a text using regex?

Tags: java, regex, string, split, words

I want to split text into words, to count the number of words.

This is how imagine it to be:

```
int words = text.split("[\\p{Punct}*\\p{Space}*]").length;
```

I've tried multiple combinations, but it seems to split into too manu parts, for example

```
"word1       word2"
```

...has 8 words with this regex, I want it to be only 2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793321/get-n-number-of-words-using-regex-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following regex:

```
[\\p{Punct}\\p{Space}]+
```

The problem with your current regex is that it matches exactly one character, and thus separately matches each whitespace between `word1` and `word2`. The repetition operator placed outside the character group fixes that.

Comment: No, it matches exactly one character, which can be punctuation, whitespace, or `*` (which is already covered by `\p{Punct}`).  The reason he gets eight substrings is because there are seven spaces between the words.  (They were only displaying as one space because he didn't use code formatting.)

Answer (score 3):

```
int countWords(String input) {
   return input.trim().split("\\s+").length;
}
```

A word is just text surrounded by whitespace. Parsing words from a `String` can be done by calling `String.split()` using `"\\s+"` as the delimiter.

Note that `"\\s+"` is a regular expression. It matches strings which consist of at least one whitespace character (such as a space, a tab, or a newline).

Answer (score 3):

```
int words = text.trim().split("\\s+").length;
```

Comment: So this would count a hyphenated-word as one word.  That may be OK.  And other than that, assuming you're other punctuation is followed by whitespace, this should do the trick just fine.

Comment: Shouldn't a hyphenated word count as only one word? Never thought about that before, I guess...

Comment: I know the unix program `wc` isn't the official standard when it comes to defining "words" or anything, but it seems to count hyphenated words as one word (not two).

Comment: @AlexLockwood - Yeah, I wasn't sure about that myself.  It was the one form of punctuation I could think of that's not surrounded by a space.

Comment: @AlexLockwood - Oh, so there's one more.  Sometimes people will not use spaces around words separated by a slash `/` even though they should.  So there may in fact be some merit to looking at punctuation as well for counting words.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), define a Splitter as Constant:

```
private static final Splitter WORD_SPLITTER = 
    Splitter.on(CharMatcher.JAVA_LETTER_OR_DIGIT.negate())
            .trimResults()
            .omitEmptyStrings();
```

and use it in your code:

```
int words = Iterables.size(WORD_SPLITTER.split(yourString));
```